# Materialize CSS sticky footer flex properties not working

Tags: css, flexbox, sticky-footer, materialize

When I apply the css properties shown for sticky footers for Materialize [here](http://materializecss.com/footer.html), the height of my main element shoots up to about 33000px. Footer shows fine, but above it is blank (presumably for a length of about 33000 pixels). The elements are arranged correctly with header, then main, then footer elements.

html:

```
<body>
    <header>
      Header stuff
    </header>
    <main>
      Main stuff
    </main>
    <footer>
      Footer stuff
    </footer>
</body>
```

sass:

```
body
  display: flex
  min-height: 100vh
  flex-direction: column

main
  flex: 1 1 auto
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was able to fix this by applying the parent flex css to a wrapper div instead of the body element, like so:

html:

```
<body>
  <div class="page-flexbox-wrapper">
    <header>
      Header stuff
    </header>
    <main>
      Main stuff
    </main>
    <footer>
      Footer stuff
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

sass:

```
.page-flexbox-wrapper
  display: flex
  min-height: 100vh
  flex-direction: column

main
  flex: 1 1 auto
```

Comment: Dude I should buy you a pizza for this! +1 up !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the other posted solutions did not work for me, however this did.

I'm using Meteor (1.1.10), fourseven:scss (3.4.1), poetic:materialize-scss (1.97.3_2), kadira:flow-router (2.10.0), kadira:blaze-layout (2.3.0)

materialize.scss

```
.site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

master-layout.html

```
<template name="masterLayout">
<div class="site">
    <header>
      {{> Template.dynamic template=navigation}}
    </header>
    <main class="site-content">
      {{> Template.dynamic template=main}}
    </main>
    <footer class="page-footer">
      {{> Template.dynamic template=footer}}
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

routes.js

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  action: function(params, queryParams) {
    BlazeLayout.render('masterLayout', {
      toolbar: 'toolbar',
      main: 'blog',
      navigation: 'navigation',
      footer: 'footer'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But was curious about the "toolbar: toolbar" in your render function? Where's that in the layout / templates?

Comment: Urm, i dont know... it must have been late... i see its there, but its nowhere else in my code... must be a relic of an experiment...

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the source of the example page you can see how they are doing it:
http://materializecss.com/footer.html

The structure below works fine for me:

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that is the same link and layout I cite as not working in the question. The reason I originally asked was because the provided example didn't work as expected.

Comment: Worked fine for me. The issue must have been caused by something in another part of your code.